# Magento override product-controller/data...?

Tags: php, json, magento

I have a Canvas-product-configurator written in pure PHP and Ajax.
Currently my Product-Configurator can save the canvas as png and  generate PDF.

Now I want to integrate the Configurator in Magento-Product-Page,
and  pass all data via JSON to Magento - if clicked on "add to Cart" Button.

in this JSON are all configured values/options. For security reasons I have to parse the values/options with in the database stored prices and get out in Cartpage..

Has someone Idea how I can pass the JSON data to Magento?
Or what is the best procedure as described?

Thanks

Comment: why not create one hidden field and pass json into hidden field

Comment: yes, its a good idea but how to manipulate it in cart

Comment: http://hemantwebsolution.blogspot.in/2014/09/programmatically-add-product-with.html check that link how to add file into cart